# Is it possible to use emmet's lorem in javascript's strings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I'd like emmet to help me with this:

```js
const str = 'lorem5|TAB'; --> const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
```

`|` cursor position

`TAB` hitting tab

Is it possible in VSCode? It works for me only with `jsx` and `html`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can but there are probably better ways to do this (such as [dedicated extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.lorem-ipsum))

---

To use emmet, just enable emmet in `*.js` files by setting:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Now the `lorem` abbreivation will work:

[image: The lorem abbreivation]

And if you have `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` set, then you can hit tab to expand the text.

However Emmet completions will not show up for the case you showed: the string `"lorem5"`. The reason is that emmet sees the closing `"` immediately after the abbreviation so it decides not to return any completions. Instead, you have to use the `Emmet: Expand Abbreviation command` (which is bound to `tab` by default) to force emmet to expand `lorem5`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In new VsCode Verison you need to following step:

Go to vs code setting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te0CA.png)

then find **emmet** in search setting

then add **javascript** in Item and **javascriptreact** in Value

Here are some screenshots that will help you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lH2e.png)